# Is a literal NSString autoreleased or does it need to be released?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, nsstring, literals

When creating a string using the following notation:

```
NSString *foo = @"Bar";
```

Does one need to release `foo`? Or is `foo` autoreleased in this case?

Comment: I am sorry to add the answer too late, but I think you should check it for the completeness as Ben's answer has some mistake in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Compiler allocated strings (of the format @"STRING") are constant, and so -retain, -release, and -autorelease messages to them are ignored. You don't have to release or autorelease foo in this case (but it won't hurt).

Comment: I find releasing foo causes my program to crash with "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: @bobobobo I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in the docs

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Tasks/MemoryManagementRules.html

> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc” or “new” or
>   contains “copy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message. You are
>   responsible for relinquishing
>   ownership of objects you own using
>   release or autorelease. Any other time
>   you receive an object, you must not
>   release it.

Since you're not using alloc, copy, etc. you don't need to worry about releasing the object.

Comment: Anything changes after ARC? I read string literals stays in memory and gets destroyed when program stops running. One should prefer creating strings using alloc over literals?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Ben\ Gottlieb at "Compiler allocated strings (of the format @"STRING") are constants" but as you have not initialized them via passing an `alloc` or `retain` message, you must not pass `release` or `autorelease` message to them otherwise your app will crash with the following log

> "pointer being freed was not
>   allocated"

**[NOTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713843/iphone-memory-management-a-newbie-question/2713941#2713941)**

```
NSString *str = [NSString string];
```

is equivalent to:

```
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

so `release` or `autorelease` must not be passed here too.