# Do NSString objects need to be alloc and init?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

Noob question:

I'm currently under the impression that when you want to create an object, you need to `alloc` and `init` that object.

However, I've seen seen several sample codes where an `NSString` object is declared, yet I see no `alloc` or `init` messages following...

A very simple example:

> ```
> NSString *myString = @"Hello World";
>
> NSLog(@"%@" , myString);
> ```

Can someone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Declaring** a variable does not require releasing any memory.

**Instantiating** objects does. And you only instantiate a new object if you call *alloc* or *copy*

In your example, you are setting your reference to the already existing object that the compiler creates from the hard-coded string. And you don't have to manage its memory because you didn't instantiate it.

I don't know if I'm explaining it clearly enough.

**EDIT:**

It looks like there is already a question that answers this:

[Is a literal NSString autoreleased or does it need to be released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329977/cocoa-memory-management-with-nsstring)

Comment: Is the `@"..."` construct declared in a header file of Foundation, Core Foundation or does the compiler handle these?

Answer (score 6):

When you embed an `NSString` literal in your code, such as `@"hello, world'`, the compiler allocates space for it in your executable file and it's loaded into memory and initialized when your program starts.

Since it's part of your executable, it lives for the whole lifespan of your app.  There's no need to retain or release it.  The `NSString *myString` variable you create for it is a pointer to the place in memory where the compiler put the `NSString` literal.