# What happens if I release a non-allocated object?

Tags: objective-c

What happens if I release a non-allocated object?

Example:

```
NSString *value = @"hello World!";

[value release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *sydill* said, string ***literals*** are different, as they don't need to be allocated or released.

Releasing other non-allocated objects OTOH, also NSStrings that are not literals, will very likely cause an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** exception.

Comment: so it may cause an exception. bad access exception: in run time

Comment: Yes, it will very likely throw the ECX_BAD_ACC exception. It depends a bit on the value in your pointer, which is simply undefined. It is very likely complete garbage, but by chance, it could be the address of another object, and that might be released (too early, but silently., i.e. no exception) or it could be nil, NULL, which would result in a no-op. It all depends on what that part of the stack contained before.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, string literals are special when it comes to memory management. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637022/557306).