# NSString allocation and initializing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring

What is the difference between:

```
NSString *string1 = @"This is string 1.";
```

and

```
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"This is string 2.];
```

Why am I not allocating and initializing the first string, yet it still works? I thought I was supposed to allocate NSString since it is an object?

In Cocoa Touch,

```
-(IBAction) clicked: (id)sender{
   NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
   NSString *newLabelText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", titleOfButton];
   labelsText.text=newLabelText;
   [newLabelText release];
}
```

Why do I not allocate and initialize for the titleOfButton string? Does the method I call do that for me?

Also, I'm using XCode 4, but I dislike iOS 5, and such, so I do not use ARC if that matters. Please don't say I should, I am just here to find out why this is so. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do NSString objects need to be alloc and init?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637022/do-nsstring-objects-need-to-be-alloc-and-init)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The variable `string1` is an `NSString` [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). The compiler allocates space for it in your executable file. It is loaded into memory and initialized when your program is run. It lives as long as the app runs. You don't need to `retain` or `release` it.

The lifespan of variable `string2` is as long as you dictate, up to the point when you `release` its last reference. You allocate space for it, so you're responsible for cleaning up after it.

The lifespan of variable `titleOfButton` is the life of the method `-clicked:`. That's because the method `-titleForState:` returns an `autorelease`-d `NSString`. That string will be released automatically, once you leave the scope of the method.

You don't need to create `newLabelText`. That step is redundant and messy. Simply set the `labelsText.text` property to `titleOfButton`:

```
labelsText.text = titleOfButton;
```

Why use properties? Because setting this `retain` property will increase the reference count of `titleOfButton` by one (that's why it's called a `retain` property), and so the string that is pointed to by `titleOfButton` will live past the end of `-clicked:`.

Another way to think about the use of `retain` in this example is that `labelsText.text` is "taking ownership" of the string pointed to by `titleOfButton`. That string will now last as long as `labelsText` lives (unless some other variable also takes ownership of the string).

Comment: Just to expand on this point, calls to `retain` and `release` on `@`-style string literals in Objective C are explicitly ignored. You can `release` it all day long and it won't be freed.

Comment: So basically, everything I have in that code is correct, and I could just remove the newLabelText string? And then user labelsText synthesized setter to set the title? I'm still kind of new, but when you say the 'setting this retain property' are you saying I should retain it?

Comment: The `labelsText.text` property retains the string you set it to. So you don't need to use `retain`, because you're using property value assignment to do that for you. See this tutorial for a longer explanation of Objective-C properties: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial