# How to declare a two dimensional array of string type in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

How do I declare a two dimensional array of string type in Objective-C?

Comment: If you're talking NS(Mutable)Array, you don't "declare" it.  An NSArray has no assigned content type, so you just declare the outer array.  How you use it is up to you.

Answer (score 44):

First, you might consider using a class to hold your inner array's strings, or loading it from a plist file (in which it is easy to make an 2d array of strings).

For direct declarations, you have a couple of options. If you want to use an NSArray, you'll have to manually create the structure like this:

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i < DESIRED_MAJOR_SIZE; i++)
{
    [strings addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"" count:DESIRED_MINOR_SIZE]];
}
```

Or, using array literals, you can get an *immutable* version like this:

```
NSArray *strings = @[ @[ @"A", @"B", @"C" ], @[ @"D", @"E", @"F" ], @[ @"G", @"H", @"I" ] ]
```

You can then use it like this:

```
NSString *s = [[strings objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j];
```

This is somewhat awkward to initialize, but it is the way to go if you want to use the NSArray methods.

An alternative is to use C arrays:

```
NSString *strings[MAJOR_SIZE][MINOR_SIZE] = {0}; // all start as nil
```

And then use it like this:

```
NSString *s = strings[i][j];
```

This is less awkward, but you have to be careful to *retain/copy* and *release* values as you put them in to and remove them from the array. (Unless you're using ARC, of course!) NSArray would do this for you but with C-style arrays, you need to do something like this to replace an array:

```
[strings[i][j] release];
strings[i][j] = [newString retain];
```

The other difference is that you can put nil in the C-style array, but not the NSArrays - you need to use NSNull for that. Also take a look at Stack Overflow question *[Cocoa: Memory management with NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329977/cocoa-memory-management-with-nsstring)* for more about NSString memory management.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to declare and initialize a two-dimensional array of strings, you can do this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item 1-1", @"item 1-2", nil],
                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item 2-1", @"item 2-2", nil],
                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item 3-1", @"item 3-2", nil],
                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item 4-1", @"item 4-2", nil],
                       nil];
```

This has the benefit of giving you an immutable array.

Comment: hi Steve McLeod, how can I get value of "item 1-1" if I have myArray like this.

Comment: [[myArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1]

Answer (score 2):

I might be self-advertising but I wrote a wrapper over `NSMutableArray` fore easy use as a 2D array. It available on GitHub as `CRL2DArray` here. https://github.com/tGilani/CRL2DArray

Comment: Coming from Android (Java) I am surprised how difficult it is to create a 2D Array in obj-C, thanks for the very useful GitHub sir!

Comment: The only problem is that I wish there was more built-in methods that a normal NSArray has like count, etc. But for now I'll just manually do it!