# How can I create array of ints

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm struggling to create an array of ints in objective c.

the way I'd do this is javascript would be:

```
arr = new Array ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2 );
```

I need to use an `NSMutableArray`, as the values need to be updated (it's a tile map for a game).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the array need to change length?

If not, why not use a normal array of ints:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2};
```

Note that an NSArray (or subclass thereof) doesn't hold `int` types natively, you have to create an NSNumber object.

If you really need an Objective-C style array, then use this:

```
int vals[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2};  // you still need this
int n = sizeof(vals) / sizeof(vals[0]);

[NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    [array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:vals[i]]];
}
```

Comment: the length does not need to change...
but i need to be able to modify the array, can i do that?
also how do i get the length of that array? [arr count] doesn't work

Comment: You might also use an NSArray and friends for a length, bounds checking, etc.

Comment: the length of the array is sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]).  This is the standard C mechanism for finding the length of a static array

Answer (score 2):

For an NSMutableArray (though a C-style array may be preferable, as suggested by Alnitak), you need to do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
```

(You can put as many as you want into that constructor, just separate them with commas and end with a `nil`.)

You could also make an empty array (`[NSMutableArray array]`) and then fill it with your ints using `[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]`.

If you need a 2D version, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638129/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-of-string-type-in-objective-c/638183#638183).

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray can only contain Cocoa objects that inherit from NSObject (ie. Apple's classes and yours).

Basically for NSMutableArray you just init it like this:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and then add/delete objects as needed.

Good luck!

PS: Hank's class reference is a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alnitak's answer, I would add that this question also suggests some confusion that I certainly felt while learning to code iPhone programming. Here are a few tips in general about programming languages on the iPhone

- Not all the code you write is objective-c.
- You can (and often should) make use of other languages in programming, most notably C.
- Alnitak's "normal array" is a C array. It is great for storing information with *primitive* data types.
- If you want to store *objects* in your array, you use an NSArray. This is not a feature available in C. We know this immediately because it starts with "NS" (incidentally, this stands for Next Step).