# how to define 2x2 array in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

how to define 2x2 or 3X.. array in ios?
like this

```
[name=john , age=21 , num=1]
[name=max , age=25 , num=2]
[name=petter , age=22 , num=3]
```

with columns
in NSMutableArray you can only add rows with objects;
i want this array[][]

Comment: What type of array? NSArrays?

Comment: You can do it all in C with this kind of notation [][].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your example, I wouldn't do it with arrays, or not just arrays.  I'd have an array of dictionaries or an array of custom objects with the properties name, age and num.  With dictionaries:

```
NSArray* theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"john", @"name",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 21], @"age",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], @"num",
        nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"max", @"name",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 25], @"age",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], @"num",
        nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"petter", @"name",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 22], @"age",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 3], @"num",
        nil],
    nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for that.. i am confused to get that value back.. could you update that please.. it may help some one like me

Comment: @Vinoth: To get the age of the middle one: `[[theArray objectAtIndex: 1] objectForKey: @"age"]`

Answer (score 3):

[How to declare a two dimensional array of string type in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638129/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-of-string-type-in-objective-c) might give you an idea

Comment: i saw that but how can i export values?

Answer (score 2):

So many ways ...

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *person = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[person setObject:@"john" forKey:@"name"];
[person setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:21] forKey:@"age"];
...

[array addObject:person];
```

... or create your custom class, which does hold all person data, or struct, or ... Depends on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be create a proper data storage class to store this in, rather than a dictionary or something like that.

e.g.

```
    @interface Person : NSObject {

    }

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* Name;
    @property  int age;
    @property  int num;

    @end
```

Then create your person instances and store them in an array.  You may wich to create some connivence methods first.    e.g.

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[Person personWithName:@"Bob",Age:1 Num:3],
                             [Person personWithName:@"Bob",Age:1 Num:3],
                              [Person personWithName:@"Bob",Age:1 Num:3],nil];
```

Its much clearer.