# NSDictionary inconsistent behaviour as params

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I've found that when using NSDictionary to create the params for an AFNetworking POST request the behaviour is inconsistent. I have multiple POSTs where the params arrive at the server in the same order I created them in the NSDictionary and now creating a new request they are arriving at the server in a different order.

This is how I send them:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": @"testuser", @"count": @"6"};
```

But this is how it arrives on the server:

```
{"count":"6","username":"testuser"}
```

Its important for me that it arrive at the server exactly the same as it leaves my app as I hash together values for integrity and can't verify if it arrives in a different order to how it leaves.

I know NSDictionary is by nature not expected to keep the order, is there anyway using NSDictionary or another way I can guarantee the order?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems ill-advised to build in that dependency.  You're dependent not only on the order of the data items, but also the precise presentation, including the presence/absence of whitespace, etc.  Easy to get burned down the road.

Comment: I appreciate that, what I'm more interested in however is why it has worked for around 20 POSTs and suddenly it is passing in the incorrect order. I take measures to remove leading and trailing whitespace and had never had any issues so its of no concern to me.

Comment: Seems to me the simplest approach would be to copy the parms into an array in a given order, or sort them once in the array.

Comment: have you explored the option of using NSArray? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638129/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-of-string-type-in-objective-c

Comment: You'll need to use an array and your own request serializer

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use an ordered dictionary class. Unfortunately, there's not one in the Foundation framework, but it's fairly easy to create (or even download) your own. This [article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) describes how to create an ordered dictionary class in Objective-C, and includes source code.