# How Objective-C handles the memory of immutable strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring, literals

In my research I've come across something peculiar.

```
@interface Class {
    NSString *_string
}

- (void) Method1 {
    _string = @"ASDF";
}
```

Intially I thought that `_string` was part of the autorelease pools and really didn't think about the memory aspect of it.

After reading this SO post [Objective C NSString* property retain count oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403112/objective-c-nsstring-property-retain-count-oddity)
I've realized that no, this is not the case, and that the retain count of `_string` is actually `UINT_MAX`

Obviously my thinking that `_string` was part of the autorelease pool was a fluke, and how I handled the variable just somehow worked out. What I would like to know, though, is: when does `@"ASDF"` get thrown away? I know I should be using properties and setters, but there is probably a lot of code out there that looks like this since assigning a constant to a variable is so intuitive.

What is the lifecycle of these immutable, literal `NSString`s, and when will `[_string length]` actually return an error since `@"ASDF"` doesn't reside in memory anymore?

Comment: You also seem to be kind of confused about how autorelease pools work. If that string were autoreleased, then (assuming ARC isn't in play) you wouldn't be managing your memory properly there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Is a literal NSString autoreleased or does it need to be released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329977/cocoa-memory-management-with-nsstring)

> Compiler allocated strings (of the format @"STRING") are constant, and
>   so -retain, -release, and -autorelease messages to them are ignored.
>   You don't have to release or autorelease foo in this case (but it
>   won't hurt).

Under the hood when you do

```
NSString* yourString = @"ABC";
```

the string will be stored in a area of memory called data segment. This area never changes after the application is launched. Here strings are treated as constants for your app. At the same time a string is an object, so if you want to keep it you call `retain` or `copy`.

On the contary when you do

```
NSString* yourString = // alloc-init
```

you create an object on the heap. If you forget to release you have a memory leak. If someone else destroy it, and you try to access it, you have a bad access to that memory location.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1289479 Is it ok for you?

Comment: Ya, it was really easy to understand your explanation so now I know how these constants work now thank you

Answer (score 0):

An immutable string (NSString) that is created manually follows the normal reference counting rules and thus life cycle.

In your example, the string is even more special because it is actually a string literal. As is the case for any literal, they reside in special memory and only get destroyed when the executable terminates.